# Weird problem with express-fileupload module saving corrupt image files to my hard drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am setting up a database for a website where I need posts to be uploaded through an HTML form, which then gets passed to a route to put the form fields into a Schema data structure. 
I am using express-fileupload to achieve this. The files I upload get saved to my database correctly, however, when writing the files to disk they end up being 0 bytes and corrupted. 
Can someone please clear this up?

I've tried using other upload modules, however, none of them seem to be as easily implementable as express-fileupload.

POSTS.JS (ROUTE FILE)

```
router.post('/create', (req, res)=>
{
  let filename = '';

  if (!isEmpty(req.files))
  {
    let file = req.files.fileUpload;
    filename = Date.now() + '-' + file.name;

    let dirUploads = './public/uploads/';

    file.mv(dirUploads + filename, (err) =>
    {
      if (err) throw err;
    });

    console.log(req.files.fileUpload);
  }
}
```

CREATE.HANDLEBARS (HTML FILE)

```
<form action="/admin/posts/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
data">
    <!-- File upload section. -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="file">Upload File</label>
      <input name="fileUpload" type="file" class="form-control" 
      id="fileupload">
    </div>
```

I expect the image file to be saved properly, as I've followed the correct implementation procedure.

Console output seems to verify that the file is properly saved to my database:

```
{ name: 'MENTORSHIPMARKETINGBLUE.png',
  data:
  <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 f4 00 
  00 01 f4 08 06 00 00 00 cb d6 df 8a 00 00 20 00 49 44 41 54 78 9c ed dd 
  77 78 56 f5 fd ... >,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '\\tmp\\tmp1550292689804',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  md5: [Function: md5],
  mv: [Function: mv] }
{ status: 'public',
  _id: 5c6796d1dc28613b845173e5,
  title: 'weg',
  allowComments: false,
  body: 'weg',
  file: '1550292689806-MENTORSHIPMARKETINGBLUE.png',
  __v: 0 }
```

However, the files saved are indeed corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact same thing happened to me too. Sometimes when you are installing the package, it doesn't install properly. Simply uninstall it, and then install it again, and make sure you have good internet while doing it. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! What a weird error, I was stressing about it for days.